# Node JS: Broken time machine - timekeeper.travel does not do to time-travelling

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, time, backend

There is a nice testing library called [Timekeeper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timekeeper/tutorial). I try to use it to test my time-dependent code but it does not seem to affect Date() at all. What do I do wrong?

```
var timekeeper = require('timekeeper');
timekeeper.travel(Date.parse("20/04/2016 12:00:00 AM"));
console.log("Time now: "+(new Date()).toLocaleString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `Date.parse()` is broken. (Your parse results in NaN btw). My spirit is weak so I always fall back on [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) to handle date/time.

```
var moment = require('moment');
var timekeeper = require('timekeeper');
var d=moment("20/04/2016 12:00:00 AM", "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss a").toDate(); 
timekeeper.travel(d); 
console.log("Time now: " + moment().format() );
```

Oh look at that, moment is already a dependency to timekeeper. I'm not the only one with a weak spirit it seems.